# phpMyAdmin give eror butlocalhost is working correctly

Tags: phpmyadmin

even i tried sudo apt install php-mbstrin it continues this eror

phpMyAdmin - Error

The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure it's enabled using:

```
sudo phpenmod mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Also you can list your current configuration by creating a file in the webserver and putting this code inside it:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

You should see the `mbstring` extension listed in that file. If not, check if you somehow have multiple versions of PHP installed and which one is being used by Apache - it will be listed in the output of `phpinfo()`

Comment: Would you mind moving your answer to OP's original question? If you leave it here, this question won't be automatically deleted